# How to change $this color, color scheme PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'd like to know why the color of `$this` in my PhpStorm isn't the one used by local variable.

I've looked through every option of the "Language Defaults" section in the settings but I couldn't find it.

[image: Here is an example]

I'm using the color scheme vim Dark, and I like it but I want to customize it by changing this color, which is too dark.

Comment: You need to specify it for the specific language (PHP), Identifiers -> Variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### CBroe said :
>
> You need to specify it for the specific language (PHP), Identifiers -> Variable.

Ok thanks CBroe, so I didn't see there were specific language sections !

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> PHP -> Identifiers