# JetBrains (PhpStorm) IDE's color scheme rule for specific word

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I've been experimenting with Color Schemas in PhpStorm and I would like to apply a certain color rule specifically for `$this` keyword. Is this even possible in PhpStorm?

Currently `$this` is regarded as a variable so the rule for variables will also be applied to `$this`. On the image below you can see which color setup I have. I would like that `$this` has similar color to parameters color (`$keyword_ids` in this case). Am I missing the rule here or is there no way to do it through PhpStorm options, maybe directly editing xml's in schemas .jar?

[image: Here]

P.S. Ping me for schema if you need it.

**Note**
There is a similar question [How to change $this color, color scheme PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735044/how-to-change-this-color-color-scheme-phpstorm) but it is not the same. This question is asking about variables in general, what I'm asking is to have a differentiation between normal variables and `$this` variable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Congrats on a well-written, appropriately-tagged, and sufficiently-researched first question. It looks like this may be an outstanding feature request https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000438190-Custom-color-for-certain-keyword There's some discussion of alternatives in the second link in the response there.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at the moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27271 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

That was for `$this` specifically. In general for custom words/keywords you may also watch after these tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33349
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7247